# How do I render a form multiple times and allow a single choice?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a quiz app and I have a choices model that contains a free text box that allows the user to type in their answer and an is_answer boolean.

I want to be able to render a form that has N choices and to allow the user to specify which of the choices is the answer as a radio box.

This is my choices form

```
class ChoiceAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = ['choice_text', "is_answer"]
        widgets = {
            'choice_text': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', })
        }
```

I am currently only able to display one instance of the form and am unsure how to allow multiple  copies of the form as part of a radio button group. Any help/insight would be appreciated :)

Comment: Can you share the `models.py`, `views.py` & `html template` code?

Comment: Did you check out modelformset?